# Using Ruby's array.bsearch_index(), is there an elegant way to look for the closest index in array so that array[i] is less than a number n?

Tags: ruby, binary-search, bsearch

I had to use something like

```
arr = [10, 20, 50, 80, 110]
(arr.bsearch_index{|a| a >= 50} || arr.length) - 1      # => 1
(arr.bsearch_index{|a| a >= 2000} || arr.length) - 1    # => 4
```

with the return value `-1` meaning there is no such index. What if the numbers could be float, so you cannot look for `49` instead when `n` is `50`.  The code right now is a little bit messy. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

(Maybe it is just how `bsearch_index()` does it: to return `nil` when not found... so we just have to use `bsearch(){ } || arr.length` to convert it back to strictly numbers -- so that's just the way it is. `bsearch_index` has to either return only numbers or it can return `nil` as a design decision and it chose to return `nil`. But I am not sure if we just have to use the code above. Maybe the `find-any` mode of `bsearch_index` or some kind of way can do it and is more elegant.)

**P.S.** it might be interesting to use a reverse() operation or negating every element or something, but since those are O(n), it defeats the purpose of using a **O(lg n)** solution using binary search and we can just do a linear search.

Comment: _"the first index in array so that [...]"_ – `1` is the index of the _last_ element smaller than 50, not the _first_ one. That would be `0`, i.e. 10.

Comment: @Stefan I see what you mean. The original question "look for the first index in array" actually was trying to mean the first one next to where 50 would be"... so I changed it. It is either "the rightmost" or the "closest" index

Answer (score 1):

In order to express "less than" directly (i.e. via `<`), you have to [`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-reverse) the array:

```
rindex = arr.reverse.bsearch_index { |a| a < 50 }
#=> 4
```

To un-reverse the index:

```
arr.size - rindex - 1
#=> 1
```

In one line:

```
arr.reverse.bsearch_index { |a| a < 50 }.yield_self { |i| arr.size - i - 1 if i }
```

The the modifier-if handles `i` being nil, e.g. `a < 10`

---

Or simply use a descending array in the first place:

```
arr = [110, 80, 50, 20, 10]
arr.bsearch_index { |a| a < 50 }   #=> 3
arr.bsearch_index { |a| a < 2000 } #=> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear, but for a sorted Array I guess:

```
arr.bsearch_index{ |a| a >= n }.then { |i| i ? i - 1 : -1}
```

Or, since `nil.to_i #=> 0`

```
arr.bsearch_index{ |a| a >= n }.to_i - 1

# n = 49 #=> 1
# n = 50 #=> 1
# n = 51 #=> 2
# n = 111 #=> -1
```

Comment: This is Θ(n), whereas the OP is looking for a binary search solution, i.e. O(log n).

Comment: BTW, you could make use of the fact that `nil.to_i #=> 0` and remove the conditional.

Comment: Picked up, @JörgWMittag. Thanks.